# Problematic keycodes 186 and 222, how to catch them

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keycode

I have a code listening keydown and I want to cancel or lock a key depending on some things ( for example text lenght, digits only, etc.)

When you press  ` or ´ (keycodes 186 and 222) chrome goes to a pseudo 'wait' state, It listens to a second key and then it shows one or two chars, depends. (I have win xp, spanish keyboard, chrome last version)

For example  186 + 80 gives : `p >> 2 characters
but          186 + 79 gives : ò  >> 1 character

I have a return code inside the event controler to validate or not the key catched.

My problem, I dont know how to cancel this 2 characters.

The question is: Is there any way to detect this behaviour? Any way to get the 'real' or 'final' character typed?

Some idea could be to inspect the text value? But when and how ? Once you have return true, the text is updated and maybe a setTimeout could be the fix.... ?

I'm a bit confussed. In addition, I suspect all depends on S.O., country cfg, etc....

Some ideas would be appreciated.

```
function keypressed (event) {
     // ------------------------------------------------
     var lock=false,chrTyped, chrCode=0, evt=event?event:event;     
     if (evt.which!=null)   chrCode = evt.which; else chrCode = evt.keyCode;
     if (chrCode==0) chrTyped = 'SPECIAL KEY';
     else chrTyped = String.fromCharCode(chrCode);
     // --------------------------------------------------- 
     //special keys & backspace [\b] work as usual:
     if (chrTyped.match(/[\b]|SPECIAL/)) return true;
     if (evt.altKey || evt.ctrlKey || chrCode<28) lock=false;

     if (lock)
     {  if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
        evt.returnValue=false;
        return false;           
     }
     else
     if (keys_used.length==0) return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you reading the value from a specific text input or getting key presses on the entire page?

Comment: @eskimo,  Yes (of course) a specific text input

Comment: Try [this fiddle (it uses jQuery though)](http://jsfiddle.net/bj077ftm/)

Comment: If it's on an input element then just use `oninput` listener and remove unwanted characters after they've been inserted. This will also replace chars in pasted text, which can't be done by locking input on `keypress` event.

Comment: @eskimo mmm but how to cancel some keys if needed? I think I need another approach.... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Chrome actually makes its work for the key combinations (Alt+key, Ctrl+Key, Shift+Key, etc.) on `'keyup'` instead of `'keydown'` as you expect. So, when you listen to `'keydown'` event it's too early, while `'keypress'` is too late stage.

You should catch `'keyup'` event and do your customization there.

Comment: Interesting, but I'd have to write more code to control the behaviour I want. For example if want to cancel any key different of a numeric digit in the middle of the input text .... Instead of a simple 'return false' on the keydown code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way is to write two eventlisteners.

The firstone to listen keydown and cancel if needed.

The second, listen keypress to know if you have 2 or more uncontrolled chars and delete them if needed. You have a little blinking but I think there is no other way